# "A"."AMOUNT": invalid identifier

Tags: sql

The following query is throwing

> "A"."AMOUNT": invalid identifier

Can anybody resolve this?

```
select s.sid, 
       a.amount 
from sale s inner join (select saleid, 
                               sum((1 - p.discount / 100) * sd.quantity  * p.price) "amount" 
                        from saledetail sd inner join product p on sd.prodid = p.prodid 
                        group by sd.saleid
                       ) a on a.saleid = s.saleid
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the double quotes:

```
select s.sid, a.amount
from sale s inner join
     (select sd.saleid, sum((1-p.discount/100) * sd.quantity * p.price) 
as amount
      from saledetail sd inner join
           product p
           on sd.prodid = p.prodid
      group by sd.saleid
     ) a
     on a.saleid = s.saleid
```

If you escape an identifier once, escape it everywhere.  Better is to drop the delimiters.

All this said, the `join` is unnecessary, assuming proper foreign key relationships on `saleid`.  So this also fixes your problem:

```
select sd.saleid,
       sum((1-p.discount/100) * sd.quantity * p.price) 
as amount
from saledetail sd inner join
     product p
     on sd.prodid = p.prodid
group by sd.saleid
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Gordon Linoff, the problem is the double quote, but you can also add it to you select column:

```
select s.sid,a."amount" from sale s inner join (select saleid,sum((1-p.discount/100)*sd.quantity*p.price) "amount"  from saledetail sd inner join product p on sd.prodid=p.prodid group by sd.saleid) a on a.saleid=s.saleid
```

Notice that  output will be lower case `amount` (with double quotes it will output `AMOUNT`)